# (html/css/javascript) Trying to make my Current Page link in the navbar a different color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been reading around and people recommending only CSS to change the current page navbar link background color but I don't get how that's possible since CSS is static and I won't be able to add/remove the `.currentlink` class on the links? So right now I'm using JS / jquery to try to add / remove class based on click, but the site refreshes and nothing is saved when I click, so that the class that I added/removed doesn't do anything. May someone guide me the right direction? Example: I click on the last link of the HTML I gave you, but it would just go to that site and since everything refreshes to a new site, the background doesn't change.

HTML

```
    <nav class="clearfix">

        <a href="#">home</a> 
        <a href="#">about us</a> 
        <a href="#">tour</a>
        <a href="index.html">flickr search</a>

    <div class="rightnav">
        <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
        <a href="#">Log In</a>
    </div>

    </nav>
```

CSS

```
.greybackground {
background: #E6E6E6;
}
```

JS

```
$('nav a').on('click', function(){
    $('nav a').removeClass('greybackground');
    $(this).addClass('greybackground');
});
```

Comment: so the only way is to add the class to the corresponding link in each of my pages?

Comment: It is not the only way... but the simplest (and generally most reliable way), yes.

Comment: Ahren is correct. However, -if- you're going to do javascript, you could either match the URL to link after the page loads, or store the most recently clicked link href in a cookie and match it to your navigation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating multi page website and want to change link color on each page, simply create a class with specific css properties and add this class to respective navbar link on each page. Make sure that on any page, class must be added to only respective page link.

Any if you are looking solution for single page website following code will work just fine

Here is html css code for simple navigation bar

```
<h1>navbar</h1>
   <li><a href="#" class="link">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="link">Products</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="link">About us</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="link">Contact</a></li>
   <button>Log in</button>
 </ul>

a{
 background-color:black;
 padding:10px;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
}

li{
 margin:30px;
 display:inline;
 }

ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 }

.transform{
 background-color:red;
 }

 button{
  background-color:green;
  padding:10px;
  color:white;
}
```

This is javascript to change bg color of active link

```
 $("a.link").click(function(){
  $("a.link").css("background-color", "black");
  $(this).css("background-color", "red");
 });
```

Simply add class '.link' for every navbar link and when user clicks on any navbar link css property ad applied to that link and all other links will change their bg color to none. I hope it helps

https://codepen.io/pranjalkoshti/pen/GMarvj

Comment: May any explanation be added?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is identify an element that

1. Is present on every page
2. You can add markup to

For example, a div for your overall content.

If you add the following to the div :

```
<div id="content" data-currentpage="about">
```

This will identify the page uniquely.

and for each menu item add a class that matches:

```
<li><a href="#" class="link" class="home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="link" class="products">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="link" class="about">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="link" class="contact">Contact</a></li>
```

So, on page ready ( jQuery(document).ready(function(){...) run the following code:

```
// -- Find the pages 'data' tag --
var currentPage = jQuery('#content').data('currentPage');
// -- Add a dot to turn it into a class identifier --
currentPage = '.' + currentPage;
// -- Add a background class to to the menu item with that class --
jQuery(currentPage).addClass('greybackground');
```

This will 'match' each page (via the data-currentpage tag) to the corresponding menu item and add your background class to that menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in vanilla JS (HTML, CSS).

Navbar items need to be in class .navlinks

Add styling under the class current-link.

```
<html>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="navlinks"></li>
            <li class="navlinks"></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</html>
```

```
<style>
.current-link {
      background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

```
<script>
  let links = document.getElementsByClassName("navlinks");
  for(let i = 0;i < links.length;i++){
    if (links[i].href.replace(/\/$/, '') == ocument.URL.replace(/\/$/, '')){
      links[i].classList.add("current-link");
    }
  }
</script>
```